# Antd form setFieldValue on OnChange event is not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have a simple form field and I am trying to format and set the field value when onChange event is triggered using setFieldsValue which is not working.

I am trying to show the formatted value in the same text field.

Please find the sandbox link here
[codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-rgb-uh203)

I dont want to create one more controlled component with state and set the value as I have 20 fields in the original form data. How could we set the form value on onChange itself.

Answer (score 2):

You are loosing the value being set because the `onChange` for Antd forms are async and are being run after the `onChange` that you have written. To get over this, you can simply add a `setTimeout` to the `setFieldsValue`:

```
onChange={e => {
  const value = e.target.value;
  const { setFieldsValue, getFieldValue } = this.props.form;
  setTimeout(() => {
    setFieldsValue({
      drivers: `+1 - ${value}`
    });
  }, 0);
}}
```

A more pragmatic way to do this, would be to use the `normalize` function of `getFieldDecorator`:

```
{getFieldDecorator(`drivers`, {
   initialValue: "",
   normalize: (value) => {
     return `+1 ${value}`;
   }
})}
```

However, this would add `+1` on every change and that doesn't look like what you would want to do. So alternatively:

```
normalize: (value) => {
  if(!value.startsWith('+1')) {
    return `+1 ${value}`;
  } 
  return value;
}
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-60471705-suws1)

Comment: thanks for the answer , but can we do this only on onBlur, eg: on onBlur event get the value format and show in the textfield, actually i want to do it for card number matching format 1234567812345678 or 1234-5678-1234-5678. If i use normalize and do it then decorateRules of regex is throwing invalid card number

Comment: @RinsenS I did not understand. you want to do it `onBlur`? But wasn't your question about doing it `onChange`?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the form value using the event too.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button } from "antd";
const FormItem = Form.Item;

class Demo extends React.Component {
  changePhone = () => {
    const { setFieldsValue, getFieldValue } = this.props.form;
    let drivers = getFieldValue("drivers");
    console.log("driver data was", drivers);
    setFieldsValue({
      drivers: `1234`
    });
  };

  handlePhoneChange = event => {
    const value = event.target.value;
    const { getFieldValue } = this.props.form;
    let drivers = getFieldValue("drivers");

    // if (!drivers.startsWith("+1 - ") && drivers.length > 3) // Another way
    if (!drivers.startsWith("+1 -"))
      // event.target.value = `+1 - `; // Another way
      event.target.value = `+1 - ${value}`;
    else
      event.target.value = `${value}`;
  };

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form>
          <FormItem
            label="phone"
            style={{
              display: "inline-block"
            }}
          >
            {getFieldDecorator(`drivers`, {
              initialValue: ""
            })(<Input onChange={this.handlePhoneChange} />)}
          </FormItem>
        </Form>
        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.changePhone}>
          change phone
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Wrapped = Form.create()(Demo);

ReactDOM.render(<Wrapped />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-hill-vuxtj